# Compare DATETIME with time() in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I would like to check how many users are online on a certain moment on a single query.
The thing is I have the time kept as **DATETIME** (in the ***online*** field) and I would like to compare it with **time()**. Here is the code:

```
$online_margin = 10; //in minutes;

$online_margin = $online_margin*60;
$difference = time() - $online_margin;

$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE online > $difference";
```

I've tried using **convert()** and **cast** but failed, so I'd appreciate some help on why...

Comment: $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(online) > $difference";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to `Y-m-d h:i:s` format before comparing it to db field,

```
$online_margin = 10; //in minutes;

$online_margin = $online_margin*60;
$difference = time() - $online_margin;
$difference  = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$difference); //Convert seconds to Y-m-d h:i:s format
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE online > $difference";
```

**Alternative:** You can convert your column `online` to unix_time for comparing,

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(online) > $difference";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is less efficient than the answer below, but it should work.

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(online) > $difference"
```